# Best practices for writing a PUT endpoint for a REST API

Tags: elasticsearch

I am building a basic CRUD service with some business logic under the hood, and I'm about to start working on the `PUT` (update) endpoint.  I have already fully written+tested `GET` (read) and `POST` (create) for my data object.  The data store for my documents is an ElasticSearch instance on AWS.

I have some decisions to make about how I want to architect the `PUT`, namely, how I want to determine a valid request.  My goal is to make it so the `POST` is **only** for the creation of new assets, and `PUT` will **only** update existing documents. (At the moment, I am `POST`ing to elastic with `/_doc/`, however the intent is to move to `/_create/` as part of this work)

What I'm a little hung-up on is the "right" way to check that a document exists before making the API call to Elastic to update.

When a user submits a document to `PUT`, should I first `GET` from Elastic with the document ID to make sure the document already exists?  Or should I simply try to "update" the resource and if it doesn't exists, one is created?

Obviously there are trade-offs to each strategy. With the latter, `PUT`ing a document that doesn't exist almost completely negates the need for a `POST` at all, so I'd be more inclined to go with the former - despite the additional REST call - to maintain the integrity of the basic REST definition.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consideration whether to update a doc (with versioning) or create a new one with some shared ID related to all previous versions depends on your use case -- either of them are 'correct' but there's too little information to advise on that right now.

With regards to the document-exists strategies -- there are essentially 2 types of IDs in ES -- what I call:

- internal ids ([`_id`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html))
- external ids ([`doc_values`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/doc-values.html#doc-values)-provided ids)

---

Create an index & a doc:

```
PUT myindex

PUT myindex/_doc/internal_id_1
{
  "external_id": "1"
}
```

### Internal ID check

```
GET myindex/_doc/internal_id_1
```

or

```
GET myindex/_count
{
  "query": {
    "ids": {
      "values": [
        "internal_id_1"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
GET myindex/_count
{
  "query": {
    "term": {      
      "_id": {
        "value": "internal_id_1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### External ID check

```
GET myindex/_count
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "external_id": {
        "value": "1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*and many others (`terms`, `match` (for partial matches etc), ...)*

Note that I've used the `_count` endpoint instead of `_search` -- it's slightly faster.

---

If you intend to check the `_version` of a given doc before you proceed to update it, replace `_count` with `_search?version=true` and the `_version` attribute will become available:

```
{
  "_index":"myindex",
  "_type":"_doc",
  "_id":"internal_id_1",
  "_version":2,             <---
  "_score":1.0,
  "_source":{
    "external_id":"1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, joe! This is exactly the kind of help i was looking for. I appreciate it.